# Load website at once, without effects

Tags: jquery

I have a website that I'm having a problem with. If I just log in the website without scrolling down, it looks like the area underneath the menu is blank. Only when scrolling down it shows up. I have got the following code and would appreciate if someone tells me how to change it so the whole website loads at once, without the effects. My website is http://shawneegaragedoors.com

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
        if(jQuery('#slider') > 0) {
        jQuery('.nivoSlider').nivoSlider({
            effect:'fade',
    });
        } else {
            jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect:'fade',
    });
        }
});


// NAVIGATION CALLBACK
var ww = jQuery(window).width();
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery(".nav li a").each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).next().length > 0) {
            jQuery(this).addClass("parent");
        };
    })
    jQuery(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
        jQuery(".nav").slideToggle('fast');
    });
    adjustMenu();
})

// navigation orientation resize callbak
jQuery(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
    ww = jQuery(window).width();
    adjustMenu();
});

var adjustMenu = function() {
    if (ww < 981) {
        jQuery(".toggleMenu").css("display", "block");
        if (!jQuery(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
            jQuery(".nav").hide();
        } else {
            jQuery(".nav").show();
        }
        jQuery(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    } else {
        jQuery(".toggleMenu").css("display", "none");
        jQuery(".nav").show();
        jQuery(".nav li").removeClass("hover");
        jQuery(".nav li a").unbind('click');
        jQuery(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('hover');
        });
    }
}

//CSS Animation
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    jQuery('.pagewrap1').each(function(){
        var imagePos = jQuery(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                jQuery(this).addClass("fadeInUp");
            }
        });

    jQuery('.pagewrap2').each(function(){
        var imagePos = jQuery(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                jQuery(this).addClass("fadeInLeft");
            }
        });

     jQuery('.postwrap3').each(function(){
        var imagePos = jQuery(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                jQuery(this).addClass("fadeInRight");
            }
        }); 


});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.srchicon').click(function() {
            jQuery('.searchtop').toggle();
            jQuery('.topsocial').toggle();
        }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `visibility: hidden` properties in your stylesheet that are being applied to `.pagewrap`, `.pagewrap2` and `.postwrap3`.  Then you can also delete the following code from the JavaScript you posted:

```
//CSS Animation
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    jQuery('.pagewrap1').each(function(){
        var imagePos = jQuery(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
            jQuery(this).addClass("fadeInUp");
        }
    });

    jQuery('.pagewrap2').each(function(){
        var imagePos = jQuery(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
            jQuery(this).addClass("fadeInLeft");
        }
    });

     jQuery('.postwrap3').each(function(){
        var imagePos = jQuery(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
            jQuery(this).addClass("fadeInRight");
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: impressive quick answer.. you beat me in typing.. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! However, I removed what you said, and it still loads the same way, where the part below the menu fades in and the part below it, too.

Comment: Actually, now I won't see the first part of the page at all- it stays blank (even after I re-inserted the codes)